# Upload fail with APK with 2 certificates entries that are valid

Tags: apk, keystore, android-keystore

I am trying to update my app in Google Developer, but receive the error:

```
>Upload failed
>
>You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your >previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are >signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
>
>[ SHA1: AF:AF:68:1E:2B:5C:99:23:4D:B9:87:F6:D6:2F:9D:5A:9A:BE:34:EC ]
>
>and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have >fingerprint(s):
>
>[ SHA1:2A:84:1D:BC:91:68:55:B1:F3:90:47:FB:3B:56:29:21:F2:38:4A:37 ]
```

However, using keytool, the keystore file contains 2 entries, both of these certificates.

How do I get Developer to except the valid entry in keystore?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution.  I had two entries because I misspelled my alias at sometime and it produced a new entry in the keystore file.

I used the keytool utility to list the contents of the keystore and to delete the wrong alias.

keytool -list -v -keystore    -- to list contents
keytool -delete -alias "" -keystore